Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 error when running multiple sql batches
I have a script that needs to run on an Azure synapse datawarehouse, the queries that run are as follows.
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas where name = 'SCHEMA1')
CREATE SCHEMA [SCHEMA1];
go
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas where name = 'SCHEMA2')
CREATE SCHEMA [SCHEMA2];

I then get the error:

Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE'.
Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE'.

I could write this as a stored procedure, but I would prefer not to, as it's a post-deployment script and wouldn't want to be creating objects on the target database.
Any ideas?

I can't talk for Azure Synapse, however, in SQL Server CREATE SCHEMA must be the only statement in the batch; I assume that is true for Synapse as well as the documentation doesn't suggest otherwise.

Does this answer your question? Can't create schema inside begin block

See the answer I suggested as a duplicate. Thom is right. This is a batch rule violation. Use EXEC to get around it, as shown in the accepted answer.

You should use only CREATE SCHEMA statement while creating schema.
I received the same ERROR when I tried the
IF  NOT  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas where name = 'SCHEMA1') CREATE  SCHEMA [SCHEMA1];


I tried approach provided @JuanR
And it worked for me.
IF  NOT  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'New')
BEGIN
EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA New;');
END;

